# when we enter the number in vb console should display that entered number multiply with stable number.how can do it.thanks a lot

Tags: vb.net, math

i am try to get value  glass supplier wants a program to find the weight of each piece of glass. Given the area and thickness of the piece of glass, the program must find weight in grams and print. Density of glass is 2.7 grams per cubic centimeter.

```
Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
    Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf + "Unit of volume?(Cubic centimetre) ")
    Dim name = Console.ReadLine()
    Dim x As Double = 2.7
    Dim y As Double

    x = y * 2.7



    Console.WriteLine(" weight is {0}", y)
    Console.Write(vbCrLf + "Press any key to exit... ")
    Console.ReadKey(True)
```

Comment: What is y? Where does it come from? Why do you expect a name from `Unit of volume?(Cubic centimeter) `? Volume is length * width * Height.

Comment: You should ask about a specific issue that you have and not how to code your whole program.